# What is the difference between an HTML Element and an HTML Tag?

Tags: html

What is the difference between an HTML Element and an HTML Tag ? 
Is there any difference with rendering ? Any there special considerations when using a tag or an element ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Element` and `Tag` are two terms that generally refer to the same thing.

When programming against HTML, however, `Tag` usually refers to a string (eg, `"<b>...</b>`), whereas `Element` refers to a DOM object representing a tag.

Answer (score 8):

- `<p>` is a tag, specifically an opening tag
- `</p>` is also a tag, a closing tag
- `<p>This is a paragraph</p>` is an element — opening tag, closing tag, and contents

Generally when you’re talking about HTML, it doesn’t *really* matter which term you use, but if we’re getting technical, the above points illustrate it.

Unless I’m missing something, you can’t use an element without using a tag (because elements are made from at least one tag), and whenever you use a tag, you’ve got an element.

Comment: ...and text nodes or comments would be neither

Comment: Indeed — there is more in HTML than is dreamed of in your tags & elements philosophy, Horatio.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you mean the HTML tag `<html></html>` which tells the browser this is an HTML document and HTML elements which are everything else as already mentioned.